# Download or Upload term?

Tags: download, upload, embedded, terminology

I am developing an PC interface that connect to an embedded device. From this interface I can modify some parameters, and I can both load data and dump data. Also I can upgrade the firmware.

How should I call the buttons on my interface?

Download data or Upload data when the goal is to send data from my PC where the interface is running, to the embedded device  on which the interface is connected.

The exact same question about the button "Download firmware" or "Upload firmware"

Of course during the transfer, a message should display "Downloading" or "Uploading".

I am confused between the choice of Download/Upload which is perfectly clear between a PC and Internet.

Where there is also the notion of the interface which is running on the PC, but which remote control the embedded target by sending commands to it. So should I see the problem from the target remote controlled through the interface running on the PC or from the PC?

This is confusing....

Comment: You always look at this from the perspective of the user's machine. If it's going to that machine, it's a download. If it's on that machine going elsewhere, it's an upload. Is there something else you aren't understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is confusing....

It is; so whatever you call it how would you expect your users to know what it means!?  The solution is to use less ambiguous terms that do not depend on the *point-of-view*.  Just be clear:

- *Update* firmware.
- *Write* device parameters.
- *Read* device parameters.